# How to know if polar graphs have inner loop.

Tags: polar-coordinates

I need to sketch the graph of r=1-2sin(x) where x is the angle between r and the horizontal axis.

When I tried sketching I saw that for (pi/6,5pi/6) the values for r are negative. I don’t understand what do we do in such cases as r is strictly greater than 0 when sketching polar graphs. Moreover, does that interval anyhow relate to an inner loop? I am having trouble identifying loops in polar graphs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzWWij96Je4

Comment: In polar, the $r$ can be negative, and the point $(-r,\theta)$ is regarded as same as $(r,\theta+\pi).$

Comment: Another way a 2D polar graph can have an inner loop is if does not have a $2\pi$ period (including if it's not periodic).